# How do I change to a directory named "-12"?

Tags: bash

I have a series of directories that are negative numbers, such as `-12`. When I try to `cd` into that directory, Bash thinks I'm using a flag of `-1`. How can I get into that directory?

Comment: `cd -- -12` will get you there.

Comment: @TimothyBrown You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways you can get into a directory beginning with a dash:

1. You can append `./` to the directory name, like this: `cd ./-12`
2. You can use `--` to tell the shell that you are done using flags, like this: `cd -- -12`

Comment: For 1, you can use `./-12` from the same directory, no need to go up a level

Comment: Note that `./-12` will work for `cd` in all versions of every Unix/Linux/Mac OS X/Xenix/etc. shell ever written. The `--` option terminator will not.

Answer (score 3):

As I stated in my comment and @LeonardBlunderbuss has also said.

Most programs (I consider all properly written programs) should understand/interpret a `--` as the end of the program arguments.

So `cd -- -12` will get you into that directory. Also note to remove it `rmdir -- -12`. etc.